# Как сделать рандом на сайте елементов

Tags: javascript, html, случайные-числа, видео

Здравствуйте)
созрел важный вопрос,на сайте есть блок с видео

---

```
<button id="click"> </button>
<div id="random_elem" style="display=none">
  <iframe src="topkino.club/embed/943779/" width="610" height="370" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe src="topkino.club/embed/1009236/" width="610" height="370" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe src="topkino.club/embed/893988/" width="610" height="370" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

как сделать чтобы видео которое выдает данная ссылка рандомилось, к примеру я захожу на сайт и вижу кнопку РАНДОМ и при нажатии выпадает рандомное видео ) буду благодарен и также если можно чтобы данный рандом не сильно грузил сайт(не скрыть елементы на сайте так как видео может быть очень много,спасибо!

Comment: А в чем смысл `display=none`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помещаете список ссылок на видео в массив 
И выбираете рандомный индекс из массива.

```
var arr = [....]

function getRandomInt(size)
{
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
}

var video = arr[getRandomInt(arr.length)]
```

Comment: спасибо,можете ли вы подсказать как правильно записать если у меня есть такой блок  
        <button id="click"> </button>
 <div id="random_elem" style="display=none">
  <iframe src="https://topkino.club/embed/943779/" 
  width="610" 
 height="370" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="https://topkino.club/embed/1009236/" 
 width="610" height="370" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
   </iframe>
<iframe src="https://topkino.club/embed/893988/" 
    width="610" height="370" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div> 

 как в масив внести елементы с Div

Comment: как именно в скрипте записать чтобы елементы которые сейчас в display=none выводились в display=block но только 1 из всего массива,не очень хорошо знаю массивы

Comment: Изучайте js. Я дал идею, ваша задача учится. Ресурс для того и создан

Comment: хорошо,спасибо)

Comment: сделал) не так много времени ушло,сам додумался